How to cross compile with software packages for RPi 3B+ using WSL2
Aim:
I would like to install packages using apt and then be able cross compile of WSL2 for RPI 3B+.
I am building on amd64 and attempting to cross compile for arm64
Description of Current Attempt:

I have installed my cross compiler on WSL2 and verified that I can build a basic hello world program
I have abstracted the toolchain description into CMAKE file and verified I can still build and run this basic program
I then attempted build the code I would actually like to run which relies on the ALSA library (asound)
This code builds for standard compilation but fails with the library not found for the cross compilation
I have tried to add a foreign architecture (arm64) and install but apt cannot find the package when attempting to update and install
Here is a link to a pull request with the whole failing setup

Questions:

Is this possible?
If so, how can I point apt to the correct location to fetch the correct prebuilt packages

Some More Context:

I am still very new to cross compilation so apologies if if the above makes little sense
_ I have not looked at virtualisation this point but I am considering it

